# Gradle Sync Fails With "UnhandledIsstesReporter"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

Here's an issue I had after Android Studio Upgrade From 3.4 to 3.5. A previously working project now fails with the following error:

> Gradle sync failed: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIssuesReporter (wrong name: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIsstesReporter)

Error Log Exception:

```
[SearchTask]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - ignore deprecated groupId: language for id: preferences.language.Kotlin.scripting 
[SearchTask]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - use other group instead of unexpected one: project.propCompiler 
[SearchTask]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - use other group instead of unexpected one: project.propCompiler 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[ thread 22]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'My Application 3'. 
[entQueue-0]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
[ thread 22]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform' (C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk) to module 'app' 
[entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
[ thread 22]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIssuesReporter (wrong name: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIsstesReporter) (29 s 205 ms) 
[ating Pool]   WARN - .idea.model.MergedManifestInfo - getMergedManifest failed Manifest merger failed : Attribute intent-filter#action:name:android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator@priority at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <priority> is provided. 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - .idea.model.MergedManifestInfo - getMergedManifest failed Manifest merger failed : Attribute intent-filter#action:name:android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator@priority at AndroidManifest.xml requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <priority> is provided. 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[entQueue-0]   WARN - un.AndroidRunConfigurationBase - Can't get application ID: Android module missing 
[ thread 25]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 9ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
[ thread 22]   WARN - ject.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler - Gradle sync failed 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIssuesReporter (wrong name: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIsstesReporter)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:306)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:302)
        at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:271)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:183)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:136)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:49)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler.setUpProject(SyncResultHandler.java:156)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler.onSyncFinished(SyncResultHandler.java:86)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncResultHandler.lambda$onCompoundSyncModels$5(SyncResultHandler.java:267)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I updated the gradle plugin version from `3.4.2` to `3.5.0` in my project's gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I then got another error:

> Gradle sync failed: Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.4.1. Current version is 5.1.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in ...\StudioProjects\BlueView\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

So I did what it suggested and modified my `gradle-wrapper.properties` files to:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

I synced project with the gradle files and after the new version of gradle had been downloaded, It failed again with the very same error:

> Gradle sync failed: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIssuesReporter (wrong name: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/issues/UnhandledIsstesReporter)

I invalidated cache and restarted Android Studio. Still No Luck.

Finally, I tried creating a brand new project. Build also failed on the brand new project template.

I searched my hard drive for this mysterious `UnhandledIsstesReporter` file and didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to export your settings, remove Android Studio and reinstall.

#### Export your settings

[image: export settings menu]

#### Uninstall Android Studio

Normally, you should be able to uninstall it from Windows Settings.

I couldn't find Android studio in Window's remove list so I ran `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\uninstall.exe`

#### Delete remaining Android Studio files

deleted the following:

- `C:\Users\<User>\.AndroidStudio3.5\`
- `C:\Users\<User>\.Android\`
- `C:\Users\<User>\.gradle\`

#### Reinstall Android Studio

I reinstalled Android Studio and it works now.

#### Import the settings you previously backed up

I imported the settings I saved before uninstalling and it still works.

Comment: It's just sad to see google delivering such bad products that need re-installation to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't uninstall anything, its hard to install all these again. i also face the same problem , i just delete my emulator from AVD and pick another and then go to project structure change the API your prefer to use. and if you have two API or SDK installed then remove tick from the useless one's from the sdk manager.

Comment: In my case, I wasn't using a virtual device, I was just trying to build an APK.

Answer (score 0):

First, **PLEASE MAKE SURE THAT YOU DON'T MIND OVERWRITING YOUR WORK** or have saved it somewhere.

Then run:

`git reset --hard origin master`

(or whatever it's called), in my case it was:

`git reset --hard origin develop`

Also, this is how I solved my problem. Your problem may have a different solution.

Here are a few other potential solutions to your problem. You may try it in any order you want though:

2. Build -> Clean Project
3. Remove emulator as Owais [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631155/5136131).
4. Restart Android Studio
5. File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
6. File -> Sync with System files
7. File -> invalidate Caches/Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart. It usually takes 10 to 30 minutes but solves a lot of similar problems (not this one in my case though).
8. Uninstall Android Studio and install it again as Jon [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631017/5136131).

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to execute the clean and build tasks of gradle to clean that error.
[image]